# Why does this loop not ackowledge the first two inputs?

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I'm writing a main method that asks the user for input in the form of the length of the radius and height of a cone, and then calls 3 other mathematical methods to determine the area of the bottom of the cone, as well as the surface area and volume of it.

The idea is that you should be able to enter several sets of inputs, and signal that you're done by entering "q". An example input could for example be " 10 5 6 8 7 5 q". The program should then calculate everything three times, with two sets of radius and height and then break the loop. Instead, it ignores the first two inputs and does the remaining four perfectly. It basically computes n-1 sets of heights and radiuses, where n is the numbers of sets provided. I'd really appreciate some help on this.

```
while(true)       //Infinite loop
{   
if (scan.hasNextInt())       //If next input is an integer, read it
    {
    radie = scan.nextInt();
    height = scan.nextInt();
    }
else if (scan.next().equals('q'))
    {                          //If it instead if "q", break the loop

    break;
    }


    do
    {   
        if (scan.hasNextInt())
        {
        radie = scan.nextInt();
        height = scan.nextInt();
        }


     System.out.print("r = "+radius);
         System.out.println("h = "+height);
         System.out.println("Bottom area:      "+ area(radius));
         System.out.println("Surface area:   "+area(radie, height));
         System.out.println("Volume:              "+ volume(radius, height));

    }while (scan.next() != "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read in two integers at first. Both integers, however, are never used in your program. Therefore, they are thrown away.

Either you eliminate the second loop and move your Outputs upward. Or, you copy your Output before the second loop.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem! I don't know how I didn't see that. I posted another comment below with the updated code, because I got another problem now. When I enter for example "10 5 3 4 q" the program should calculate two sets of inputs, and then move on. However, it now calculates three sets, where the lasts two are identical. Any guesses on why that might be?

Comment: Because your `else if (scan.next().equals('q')) break;` statement checks for  a `char` 'q' but the scanner reads it as a whole `string` because your are calling `scan.next()` input token and thus doesn't break the while loop. Surround your `q` with double quotes. Check the first code snippet of my answer.

Comment: Also, post your edits below the original question itself instead of submitting it as an answer. Consider moving it in the question and deleting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your code is that you are never using the first two `int` scanned in the `while` loop. Do this instead:

```
    while (true)       //Infinite loop
    {
        if (scan.hasNextInt())       //If next input is an integer, read it
        {
            radius = scan.nextInt();
            height = scan.nextInt();
        } else if (scan.next().equals("q")) break;
        System.out.print(radius);
        System.out.println(height);
    }`
```

Alternatively, just check for `int`:

```
int radius;
int height;

//provided user would be entering radius and height in pairs
while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
    radius = scan.nextInt();
    height = scan.nextInt();
    //Call your methods
}
```

Alternatively, since you don't know the number of parameters user would be entering, it'd be better if you create an `ArrayList` for radius as well as height and add inputs to the list and then process them from the list. This would help you preserve input even after exiting `while` loop:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> radiusList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> heightList = new ArrayList<>();


    while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        radiusList.add(scan.nextInt();
        heightList.add(scan.nextInt());
    }

    int radius;
    int height;
    for (int i = 0; i < radiusList.size(); i++) {
        radius = radiusList.get(i);
        height = heightList.get(i);
        //Call your methods.
    }
```

Comment: That's a smart way to go about doing it! I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true)       //Infinite loop
{   
if (scan.hasNextInt())       //If next input is an integer, read it
{
radie = scan.nextInt();
height = scan.nextInt();
}
else if (scan.next().equals('q'))
{                          //If it instead if "q", break the loop  
    break;
}
     System.out.print("r = "+radius);
     System.out.println("h = "+height);
     System.out.println("Bottom area:      "+ area(radius));
     System.out.println("Surface area:   "+area(radie, height));
     System.out.println("Volume:              "+ volume(radius, height));

}

}
```